# Should I use an S3 bucket with my form_for image uploader?

Tags: javascript, ruby, forms, ruby-on-rails-4

I am looking to implement something like https://my.charitywater.org/p/campaignCreate (step 2) where a user can choose from a list of images to use. They are using fancybox which I am kind of familiar with so could use that in my implementation.

I would like to be able to incorporate this into my form_for.

I currently use carrierwave so a user can upload their own images, but I'm not sure if I should be storing my default images in a s3 bucket, for example, and pull them down from there (though will be re-uploading images already stored so unsure on performance implications there).

Is there a good place to start with this? Anything I should be thinking about here?

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to use save images using remote urls in **Carrierwave** (see this [Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5007575/how-to-assign-a-remote-file-to-carrierwave)).

What I would do is build an interface with a sample of images pluged to a *select* input, which stores the **url** of each image.
So that when the user submits the form, you have a field **remote_image_url** set.

**Edit**

But as you stated it would store images various times.

You can also have a list of **image** in your database attached to a model and use a rails relationship to link them.