# Carrierwave thumb method doesn't work for remote image url

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin, carrierwave

I have a model with two fields img_file (to load from computer) and img_url (to load remotely from internet). I have a standart thumb method in my ulpoader.

```
 version :thumb do
   process :resize_to_fit => [50, 50]
 end
```

The problem is that, when I call this method for img_file it works, but doesn't for img_url.

Here is my code:

```
f.inputs do
   f.input :project_id, as: :select, collection: Project.all {|p| [p.title]}
   f.input :img_file, as: :file, hint: image_tag(f.object.img_file.thumb)
   f.input :img_url
end
```

This is how I call thumb method for both:

```
column :img_file do |photo|
  image_tag photo.img_file.thumb
end

column :img_url do |photo|
  image_tag photo.img_url.thumb
end
```

It seems to be a silly question, but I'm stuck with. Hope, anyone see the problem. Thanks!

Comment: I think it's coming from the naming you've used `img_url` specifically the `_url` part. Just to be sure rename it to something else and check again.

Comment: @Marwen, thanks for your reply! I've renamed it to img_remote, but now when I call thumb method, it says **undefined method `thumb' for #<String:0x007fba9c011478>**

Comment: You have to replace `img_url` by `img_remote` everywhere in your code. Also try with a newly created `record` after updating you `migration`

Comment: @Marwen, I renamed it everywhere, migrated, but it still not working. So strange...

Comment: After renaming, did you get the same `error` or a new one?

Comment: @Marwen, the same error **undefined method `thumb' for #<String**. If want to show the image with image_tag, it's working. But if I write **image_tag(photo.img_remote.thumb)** - it gives an error. With **img_file** (loaded from computer) it's working.

Comment: Okay, I found an answer that might help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5007575/how-to-assign-a-remote-file-to-carrierwave